# Data Structure for matching a string

Tags: java, data-structures

I am having a set of strings, and if am passing some words as input from actual dataset , it have to find the string which contains the particular words... for doing such a task which data structure i can use. can anyone help me to find out.

Comment: you can use `string.contains("words");`

Answer (score 1):

The usual data structure for finding a string in a dictionary is a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (also called a trie). There's lots of info on the web for how to implement it. There's a nice article [here](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2011/07/coding-up-trie-prefix-tree.html), for instance.

For matching (finding a particular substring in another string), the best data structure is a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). Again, lots of info available on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Suffix tree is useful for string pattern matching.